# Wrong parameter received in function call

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

Why do I receive subject (object that I want) on first item but MouseEvent from all other subject changes?

```
<template v-for="subject in subjects">
  <select v-model="subject.name" class="form-control" @change="setNote(subject)">
    <option v-for="vsub in validSubjects" :value="vsub.id_subject">{{ vsub.name }}</option>
  </select>
</template>
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    message: 'Choose a subject: ',
    subjects: [{
      name: "Maths"
    }, {
      name: "Science"
    }],
    validSubjects: [{
      id_subject: "1",
      name: "Maths"
    }, {
      id_subject: "2",
      name: "Science"
    }, {
      id_subject: "3",
      name: "English"
    }]
  },
  methods: {
    setNote(subject) {
      console.log(subject);
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  {{ message }}
  <template v-for="subject in subjects">
  <select v-model="subject.name" class="form-control" @change="setNote(subject)">
    <option v-for="vsub in validSubjects" :value="vsub.id_subject">{{ vsub.name }}</option>
  </select>
</template>
</div>
```

Comment: Works for me only on first subject. Try adding a second subject. Then selecting value on second subject passes MouseEvent instead of subject to a method setNote.

Comment: @Tim I added another subject now and it still seems to work. Any chance you could write a reproducible example?